# Using react-native-auth0 quick start without AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, react-native, auth0, expo

The `react-native-auth0` quick start:

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/react-native/00-login

requires you to modify the `AndroidManifest.xml` in order to use WebAuth:

```
auth0
  .webAuth
  .authorize({scope: 'openid email',
              audience: 'https://{myauth0app}.au.auth0.com/userinfo'})
```

However, the latest React-Native quick start, created via:

```
create-react-native-app
```

does not include a `AndroidManifest.xml`. Is it possible to use `react-native-auth0` with the latest version of React-Native?

Currently I have found that the `react-native-auth0` quick start results in the following error:

```
[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'A0Auth0.oauthParameters')]
```

**EDIT**

From the react-native quick start, you can get to a project with an `AndroidManifest.xml` by running

```
npm run eject
```

However, this removes the app from the Expo framework. Is it possible to get Auth0 working within the Expo framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gathered, it's possible to get Auth0 working with Expo app. You just need to handle most wiring and API calling yourself without relying on something like `react-native-auth0`. There's a guide here (albeit a bit outdated): https://github.com/expo/auth0-example